# How can I set up OAuth2 bearer tokens for an ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: c#

So I had a set up with PHP using Laravel passport, I want to achieve the same thing with my ASP.NET core web api.

Researched it a lot and came back with nothing, there just isn't much material out there, at least not much that is simple to understand for a beginner like me.

I have come across Identity Server 4 but for this I have been told it is overkill.

All of the tutorials, blog posts, videos, etc are showing how to do this with an external provider, I don't want an external provider, I just want to do it on my own server, my own API.

Can someone help in where I start for this? What packages are availble? I am using ASP.NET 3.0 with a JS framework based frontend.

Comment: use identifyserver 4 password flow to authenticate user. In this flow user get validate from back channel with credentials. There will be no need of any UI , simple existing login is sufficient to implement. You can do it with own server and own api with this flow

Comment: As an alternative, you can use built-in ASP.NET Core Identity which generates json web token. It is simple and interesting. Please, read [this great article about ASP.NET Core, Angular 2+ and JWT](https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-1/).